# Is there any functionality like $rootScope in angular cli 4?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I want one variable value from one component to another component. please let me know how can I achieve it in angular 4?

Comment: Use a shared service. There is nothing else close to a `$rootScope`

Comment: How to use shared service?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html